# CSS - Paragraph is stretching the width of the DIV

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, paragraph

Currently I have a paragraph inside a div. The div stretches with I put in a long text as the paragraph when viewed in mobile mode (768px). When I replaced the long text with a short text for example 'Box One', it does not stretch the div as I have not exceed the div width. How can I make the paragraph break into a new line when it reaches the div width when viewed in mobile mode? I have attached my jsfiddle as an example.

https://jsfiddle.net/ModestGrey/az4ca9j8/

HTML

```
<div class="boxes">
<div class="one box"><p>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</p></div>
  <div class="two box"><p>Box Two</p></div>
  <div class="three box"><p>Box Three</p></div>
  <div class="four box"><p>Box Four</p></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.boxes {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  height: 15em;
  color: #fff;
}

.one {
  background: #333;
}

.two {
  background: #fff;
  color: #333;
}

.three {
  background: #aaa;
}

.four {
  background: #dc002e;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:48em) {
  .boxes {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .box {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .three {
    display: table-caption;
  }
  .four {
    display: table-caption;
  }
  .one {
    display: table-caption;
  }
  .two {
    display: table-caption;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
.box { display: block; float: left; }
.one.box p { overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/60Lmtdtd/

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [word-wrap](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp) within your `@media` to force-break long words:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: Nope, it does not break into another line.

Comment: @ModestGrey it does, look at [your updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/az4ca9j8/8/).

Answer (score 0):

use the css `word-wrap: break-word;` to Allow long words to be able to break and wrap onto the next line.

Comment: Added `word-wrap: break-word` it does nothing.